# How to create a GObject final class with both public and private members?

Tags: c, oop, glib, gobject

In the chapter *Boilerplate code* of [GObject Manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject-code.html), when ViewerFile is declared as a final type using *G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE*, how can we add public data to it since it is hidden behind the *viewer-file.c* which is not included?

Comment: In general you should provide functions to access data instead of letting external code access the struct members directly.  GNOME has been doing this for a while now (see https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/GnomeGoals/UseGseal for details on the transition).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main distinction between a "derivable" GObject type and a "final" GObject type is the visibility of the instance data structure.

If the GObject type is "derivable" then you can only use a private instance data structure, as the instance structure is public and it's generated to just include the parent's structure.

If the GObject type is "final" then you only get instance fields, since the instance data structure is private to your C source file.

You cannot mix the two approaches, unless you decide *not* to use the macros and write the boilerplate by hand.

Additionally, you should not *ever* access fields on an instance data structure; provide accessor functions, instead, so that you can validate pre-conditions and post-conditions safely.